# I want to remove the last item discord.py

Tags: python, split, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot that will help managing tasks.
Currently, I want to remove the date from the task string. But I am kinda stuck.
I tried some stuff with the .split method. But apparently, there is a two arguments cap.
I didn't find a helpful post on here so I hope someone can help me...

```py
if message.content.startswith(PREFIX + COMMAND_TASK):
    subject = message.content.split(' ')[1]
    task = message.content.split(' ', 2)[2:]
    date = message.content.split(' ')[-1]
    task = task[:task.find(date)-1] 

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour(0xbd10e0))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnailurl)
    embed.add_field(name="subject",
                    value=subject,
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="task",
                    value=str(task)[2:-2],
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="date",
                    value=date,
                    inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

It looks like this:
[image: text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of the date in the string via [find()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find)

The task description will become

```
subject = message.content.split(' ')[1]
task = message.content.split(' ', 2)[2:]
date = message.content.split(' ')[-1]
task = task[:task[0].find(date)-1]  # -1 so that we don't have the last space that is before 03
```

Now, your task should be exactly "A description of the task"

Comment: That produces an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: @Akorian Could you `print(task)` right before `task = task[:task.find(date)-1]` so I can adapt my modification to your structure ?

Comment: print output: ['A description of the task 03/01/2020']

Comment: I have updated my answer, it simply needed `task[0].find(...` instead of `task.find(...`
After that line of code, `task` will be a string containing "A description of the task"

Comment: Doesn't work. The date is still appending the subject

Comment: Ok, my bad, maybe date is also not how I expected it, could you `print(date)` right before `task = task[:task[0].find(date)-1]` ? I thought it was a string but maybe it is also a list containing a string

Comment: Print output: 03/01/2020

Comment: My bad again, `task = task[0][:task[0].find(date)-1]` should work instead of `task = task[:task[0].find(date)-1]`, if it still doesn't work i'll delete my answer since it is not working